# Why can't I assign my merge request to a specific user in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

We are using gitlab to serve our git repositories. Now I've cloned our master project to track my own changes and now I would like to create a merge request to the master again. When I look at the youtube movie, I can see Job selecting a user to assign the merge request to. In my version this whole drop-down box is missing.

Is this because I use version 6.8.2, is it because I do a merge request from a fork? What is happening here?

I would like to be able to select an other team member to review the commit before merging it into the master project.

Answer (score 2):

You're able to assign it to someone on the next screen. We agree that this flow is not ideal so we changed it in 6.9 https://www.gitlab.com/2014/05/22/gitlab-6-9-ee-and-ce-release/

Comment: Thanks! I've upgraded our server this morning and the work-flow is a lot more intuitive.